# cropping image in svelte The first argument is required and must be an <img> or <canvas> element

Tags: javascript, svelte

I am struggling to get cropperjs to work in svelte. Any help would be appreciated.

The svelte script is as follows

```
<script>
import Cropper from 'cropperjs';

const image = document.getElementById('image');

const cropper = new Cropper(image, {
  aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
  crop(event) {
    console.log(event.detail.x);
    console.log(event.detail.y);
    console.log(event.detail.width);
    console.log(event.detail.height);
    console.log(event.detail.rotate);
    console.log(event.detail.scaleX);
    console.log(event.detail.scaleY);
  },
});


</script>
<img id="image" src="./images/favicon.png" alt="">
```

The error is:

```
Uncaught Error: The first argument is required and must be an <img> or <canvas> element.
    at new Cropper (cropper.js:3229:15)
    at instance$1 (Example5.svelte:8:14)
    at init (index.mjs:1809:11)
    at new Example5 (Example5.svelte:17:36)
    at create_fragment (Example5.svelte:17:36)
    at init (index.mjs:1824:37)
    at new App (Example5.svelte:17:36)
    at main.js:3:13
    at main.js:7:2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There appears to be an issue using `import Cropper from 'cropperjs'`. Corrl supplied a work-around in a comment:

> There seems to be a problem with `import Cropper from 'cropperjs';`
> inside the REPL - when using `<svelte:head>` with script and stylesheet
> references to Cropper it looks better

Another problem is that the image hasn't completed loading by the time you pass the reference to `Cropper`.  You could try using [`onMount`](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/onmount) instead which runs after the component is added to the dom. However, the image data hasn't always completed loading when `onMount` runs.

Another option is to bind to the `onload` event for the image. This answer to [Svelte component onLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65000691/9665021) shows the technique. However, you could simply call `img.addEventListener('load', initCropper);` within `onMount` which will initialize Cropper once the image has fully loaded.

```
<svelte:head>
    <link  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/2.0.0-alpha.2/cropper.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/2.0.0-alpha.2/cropper.min.js"></script>
</svelte:head>

<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte'

    let img, cropper;
    
    onMount(() => {
        // call initCropper when img is loaded   
        img.addEventListener('load', initCropper);
    });

    function initCropper() {
        cropper = new Cropper(img, {
            aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
            viewMode: 2,
            crop(event) {
                console.log(event.detail);
                console.log(event.detail.y);
                console.log(event.detail.width);
                console.log(event.detail.height);
                console.log(event.detail.rotate);
                console.log(event.detail.scaleX);
                console.log(event.detail.scaleY);
            },
        });     
    }
</script>

<div>
    <img {src} bind:this={img} />  
</div>
```

The code above works for me, you can see a [demo here](https://svelte.dev/repl/5cc1a73f6438414088ab69ee4915e4ce?version=3.46.3).

---

**Alternative**

There is a cropping library - [svelte-easy-crop](https://github.com/ValentinH/svelte-easy-crop) - which works with Svelte. The code below is taken from the [demo](https://svelte.dev/repl/a6fc511aafd94e428d0bb6670f477abc?version=3.4.4):

```
<script>
  import Cropper from "svelte-easy-crop";

  let crop = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  let zoom = 1;
  let image = "https://cdn1-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/2011/03/puppy-development.jpg";
</script>

<Cropper {image} bind:crop bind:zoom />
```

Comment: The DOM not being loaded can’t be the cause. The OP’s code is incomplete: `import` is only valid in a module, so it should’ve been `<script type="module">`, which is missing. But modules defer by default, so the DOM is definitely ready at this point. The image not being loaded may be the actual issue, but it’s independent of the DOM being ready, and, at any rate, it’s not being communicated clearly in the error message…

Comment: There seems to be a problem with `import Cropper from 'cropperjs';` inside the REPL -  when using `<svelte:head>` with script and stylesheet references to Cropper it looks better [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/7518c644c89842d7aa27514bcf3dd2a1?version=3.46.3) (The `Cropper is not defined error` is a bug of the REPL, simply add a line before the `<svelte:head>` element and it should work...)

Comment: *"so the image hasn't loaded yet"* Inside the REPL I linked in the last comment there's a log to the `img.complete` property [which indicates whether or not the image has completely loaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/complete) inside `onMount` - sometimes resolving to `false`. So what's given inside `onMount` is that component and image are mounted and the reference to the image element via the assigned `bind:this` variable works, but loading the image data might still be in progress and finish later (could be listened for on the image with `on:load`)

Comment: Thanks @Corrl, you're right about the import not working correctly in Svelte. Updated my answer to use the image loaded event to initialize Cropper

Comment: I'm sorry, I think my comment might have been misleading... I didn't want to say that you have to wait for the `load` event of the image. Quite the opposite - Cropper doesn't care if the image is loaded or not, it only needs the reference to the image element, which is given inside onMount...

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to initializing Cropper inside onMount would be `use:action` > [Docs](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-use-action) > [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/6d81a9200c7040449580b200a9d96f4b?version=3.46.3)

```
<svelte:head>
    <link  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/2.0.0-alpha.2/cropper.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/2.0.0-alpha.2/cropper.min.js"></script>
</svelte:head>

<script>
    let cropper;
    
    function initCropper(node){
        console.log('loaded', node.complete)
        cropper = new Cropper(node, {
            aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
            crop(event) {
                console.log(event.detail);
                console.log(event.detail.y);
                console.log(event.detail.width);
                console.log(event.detail.height);
                console.log(event.detail.rotate);
                console.log(event.detail.scaleX);
                console.log(event.detail.scaleY);
            },
        });     
    }
</script>

<div>
    <img use:initCropper src="https://cdn1-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/2011/03/puppy-development.jpg" alt="">
</div>

<style>
    img {
        display: block;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes the suggestion by Corrl was spot on. Adding the head elements sorted out the problem. Also the point by haldo, about using onMount is required as well.